# How to make double back press app exit in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to exist app when i double tap android back button, but WillPopScope widget have no effect because (I think) there are already scaffold widgets.

If i could remove them, i would already did but I can't. Is there any other way I can make it? Here's code.

```
import 'package:eqms_test/Api/DraggableSheetModel.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Api/GoogleMapModel.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Widgets/EQInfo/EQInfo.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Widgets/EQSafety/eq_safety.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Widgets/SensorDetails/SensorInfo.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Widgets/SensorMap/SensorMap.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/Widgets/MorePage/more_page.dart';
import 'package:eqms_test/style/color_guide.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class RootScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RootScreen> createState() => _RootScreenState();
}

class _RootScreenState extends State<RootScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final PageController _controller;
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> eqInfoNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> eqSafetyNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> sensorMapNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> sensorDetailsNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> morePageNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  late List<Widget> widgetOptions;
  DateTime? currentBackPressTime;

  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomItems = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/eq_info.svg'),
      activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/eq_info_selected.svg'),
      label: '1',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/eq_safety.svg'),
      activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/eq_safety_selected.svg'),
      label: '2',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/sensor_map.svg'),
      activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/sensor_map_selected.svg'),
      label: '3',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/sensor_info.svg'),
      activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/sensor_info_selected.svg'),
      label: '4',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/setting.svg'),
      activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/setting_selected.svg'),
      label: '5',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController();

    widgetOptions = [
      Navigator(
          key: eqInfoNavigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const EQInfo());
          }),
      Navigator(
          key: eqSafetyNavigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => EQSafety(goToEQInfo: goToEQInfo));
          }),

      Navigator(
          key: sensorMapNavigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SensorMap());
          }),
      Navigator(
          key: sensorDetailsNavigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SensorInfo());
          }),
      Navigator(
          key: morePageNavigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const MorePage());
          }),
    ];
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();  // Dispose of the controller when not needed
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (!mounted) return;

    if (selectedIndex != index) {
      _controller.jumpToPage(index);
    }
  }

  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() => selectedIndex = index);
  }
  void goToEQInfo() {
    if (!mounted) return;

    _controller.jumpToPage(0);
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = 0;
    });
  }

  BottomNavigationBar renderBottomNavigationBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      elevation: 0,
      items: bottomItems,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      unselectedItemColor: mediumGray,
      selectedItemColor: primaryDark,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      onTap: onItemTapped,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GoogleMapModel>(create: (context) => GoogleMapModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DraggableSheetModel>(create: (context) => DraggableSheetModel()),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          controller: _controller,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,  // Use onPageChanged here
          children: widgetOptions,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 58,
              child: renderBottomNavigationBar()),
        ),
        extendBody: false,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I checked onWillPop but it doesn't even call when i click back button, and I tried double_back_to_close_app library but no use.

Scaffold widgets are nested like

Rootscreen(Scaffold) - EQInfo(stles) - Scaffold - GoogleMap .... in some pages.

For more information, here's main and splash

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await FirebaseMessageApi().initNotifications();

  final GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform mapsImplementation =
      GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance;
  if (mapsImplementation is GoogleMapsFlutterAndroid) {
    mapsImplementation.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
    mapsImplementation.initializeWithRenderer(AndroidMapRenderer.latest);
  }

  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: SplashScreen(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}
```

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}): super(key:key);
  @override
  SplashScreenState createState() => SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late bool isFirstTime;

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigateAfterSplash();
  }

  Future<void> navigateAfterSplash() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('first_time') ?? true;

    Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          () async {
        if (isFirstTime) {
          await setFirstTimeFalse();

          _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(PageTransition(
            type: PageTransitionType.fade,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            child: const InitialIntroduction(),
          ));
        } else {
          _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(PageTransition(
            type: PageTransitionType.fade,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            child: const RootScreen(),
          ));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String imageLogoName = 'images/LOGO.png';
...
```

+) This is when i add willpopscope in class RootScreen. and onWillPop is not being called. (nothing print on log console)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GoogleMapModel>(
            create: (context) => GoogleMapModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DraggableSheetModel>(
            create: (context) => DraggableSheetModel()),
      ],
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          print('onWillPop');
          DateTime now = DateTime.now();
          if (currentTime == null ||
              now.difference(currentTime) > const Duration(seconds: 2)) {
            //add duration of press gap
            currentTime = now;
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text(
                    'Press again to exit')));
            return Future.value(false);
          } else {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
            exit(0);
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            onPageChanged: onPageChanged, // Use onPageChanged here
            children: widgetOptions,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
            child: SizedBox(height: 58, child: renderBottomNavigationBar()),
          ),
          extendBody: false,
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on backPressed method put the timer of 200ms, to count the back press count, if its 2 or greater then this in 200 ms, exit from the app programatically.

Comment: if onbackPressed method is for WillPopScope, no use. I already stated that onWillPop is not calling when i tap backbutton

Answer (score 1):

First create `currentTime` variable in State like:

```
  var currentTime;
```

Then you gotta wrap your main widget(like `Scaffold`) in WillPopScope and fill `onWillPop` property of it like

```
      onWillPop: () async {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        if (currentTime == null ||
            now.difference(currentTime) > const Duration(seconds: 2)) {
          //add duration of press gap
          currentTime = now;
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                  'Press again to exit'))); 
          return Future.value(false);
        } else {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
          exit(0);
        }
      },
```

**End Result**

[image: preview]

Comment: I tried several method at onWillpop, but onWillPop itself doesn't call when i tap back button...

Comment: Did you try it with my code too? Because I just tested it and it worked

Comment: yes. I wrapped Rootscreen scaffold with WillPopScope, but still not calling onWillPop.

Comment: Maybe you are missing something. Can you show me an example of you using WillPopScope?

If you don't want to share your code, you can also try adding a breakpoint to the WillPopsScope line and run debug. 
Also, adding print statements inside onWillPop might help too.

Comment: You can share preview with code

Comment: sorry for late. i edited the post. onwillpopscope itself doesn't call.

Comment: Did you try to wrap "MultiProvider" with WillPopScope? I think WillPopScope should be most outer widget in the tree